# SQL Server Recursive Query to get Top parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need your help on making on recursive query using a CTE in SQL Server.

I have order no as input parameter.. I need to display its top parent despatch details. even if I search for its children.. ie if I search for order no 3 I should get its top parent order no. that is 20.

Here is my table structure..

```
CREATE TABLE #TblSerialNo
    (
      [SRno] [char](20) NOT NULL ,
      [CustSrNo] [varchar](75) NULL
    )
CREATE TABLE #TblSerialReleation
    (
      [SRno] [char](20) NOT NULL ,
      [ChildSRno] [char](20) NOT NULL
    )
CREATE TABLE #TblDespatch
    (
      [SRno] [char](20) NOT NULL ,
      OrderNo INT NOT NULL
    )

INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo   VALUES  ( 'TS1', 'DD123CV1' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo   VALUES  ( 'TS2', 'DD123CV2' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo  VALUES   ( 'TS3', 'DD123CV3' )

INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'BS1', 'DD12sfs3CV1' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'BS2', 'DD1et23CV2' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'CS1', 'DD12e3CV1' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'CS2', 'DD12fe3CV2' )

INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'BS1aa', 'DD12d3CV1' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'BS1ab', 'DDd123CV2' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'BS1ac', 'DD1r23CV3' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'BS2aa', 'DDs123CV4' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'BS2ab', 'DD12d3CV1' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'BS2ac', 'DD1s23CV2' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'CS1aa', 'DD1s23CV3' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'CS1ab', 'DD12s3CV4' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'CS1ac', 'DD123dCV1' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'CS2aa', 'DDa123CV2' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'CS2ab', 'DDa123CV3' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialNo VALUES  ( 'CS2ac', 'DDa123CV4' )

--================  Relation table   ==============

INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'TS1', 'BS1' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'TS1', 'BS2' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'TS2', 'CS1' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'TS2', 'CS2' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'BS1', 'BS1aa' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'BS1', 'BS1ab' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'BS1', 'BS1ac' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'BS2', 'BS2aa' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'BS2', 'BS2ab' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'BS2', 'BS2ac' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'CS1', 'CS1aa' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'CS1', 'CS1ab' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'CS1', 'CS1ac' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'CS2', 'CS2aa' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'CS2', 'CS2ab' )
INSERT  INTO #TblSerialReleation  VALUES  ( 'CS2', 'CS2ac' )
--===========  Despatch 
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'CS2ac', 1 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'CS2ab', 1 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'CS2ac', 1 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'CS1aa', 1 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'CS1ac', 1 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'CS2ac', 1 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'CS2ac', 1 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'TS1', 1 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'TS3', 2 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'TS2', 3 )
INSERT  INTO #TblDespatch  VALUES  ( 'BS2ab', 20 )

DROP TABLE #TblDespatch
DROP TABLE #TblSerialNo
DROP TABLE #TblSerialReleation
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like we're missing something here -- how do they link (if you were to do it by hand now)?  I'm not seeing the relationship in the data above.

Comment: @sgeddes it appears to be in the `TblSerialReleation` table

Comment: @w0lf -- I see that it's suppose to be there -- but I can't figure out how TS2 matches back to BS2ab (20) in the despatch table -- I don't see it :)

Comment: @sgeddes correct, there are some missing links there :)

Comment: Can serialNo entry has more than one parent?

Comment: There is a relation between all the table to TblSerialNo. SRno is d key..

Comment: Please assume there is a proper foreign key relation between all the table. TblSerialReleation  contain relation between parent and child. Child can be a parent .  There are also parent with out any child. we can dispatch any child or parent from any hierarchy.

Comment: Can serialNo entry has more than one parent?  NO..

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your data, the relation seems to go the other way around (`BS2ab` (Order 20) is the child of `TS1`(Order 3) through `BS2`.

If this is the case, starting from the child (`BS2ab`) you can find its top parent with the following statement:

```
;with ParentOrders as(
  select 
    convert(char(20), 'BS2ab')as SRno,
    0 as Level 

  union  all

  select r.SRno, o.Level + 1
  from ParentOrders o
  join TblSerialReleation r
    on o.SRNo = r.ChildSRno 
)
select top 1 SRNO 
  from ParentOrders
  order by Level desc
```

Here's a working sample of the query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e253e/6